# Android Studio não reconhece o método getRating()

Tags: android, método, syntax-error

Quando eu tento utilizar o método getRating() na classe FormularioHelper o Android Studio informa que "Cannot resolve method 'getRating()'".

Estou importando o pacote da View e do RatingBar e mesmo assim o Android Studio não reconhece esse método.

**O que devo fazer para que o método getRating() funcione?**

**Código**

```
package com.alura.magnero2018.agendaalura;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

import com.alura.magnero2018.agendaalura.FormularioActivity;
import com.alura.magnero2018.agendaalura.R;


import alura.modelo.Aluno;

public class FormularioHelper extends View
{
    private EditText campoNome;
    private EditText campoEndereco;
    private EditText campoSitesPessoais;

    public EditText getCampoNome() {
        return campoNome;
    }

    public void setCampoNome(EditText campoNome) {
        this.campoNome = campoNome;
    }

    public EditText getCampoEndereco() {
        return campoEndereco;
    }

    public void setCampoEndereco(EditText campoEndereco) {
        this.campoEndereco = campoEndereco;
    }

    public EditText getCampoSitesPessoais() {
        return campoSitesPessoais;
    }

    public void setCampoSitesPessoais(EditText campoSitesPessoais) {
        this.campoSitesPessoais = campoSitesPessoais;
    }

    public EditText getCampoTelefone() {
        return campoTelefone;
    }

    public void setCampoTelefone(EditText campoTelefone) {
        this.campoTelefone = campoTelefone;
    }

    public EditText getCampoNotas() {
        return campoNotas;
    }

    public void setCampoNotas(EditText campoNotas) {
        this.campoNotas = campoNotas;
    }

    private EditText campoTelefone;
    private EditText campoNotas;

    public FormularioHelper(FormularioActivity activity)
    {
        EditText campoNome = activity.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        EditText campoEndereco = activity.findViewById(R.id.endereco);
        EditText campoSitesPessoais = activity.findViewById(R.id.sitesPessoais);
        EditText campoTelefone = activity.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
        RatingBar campoNotas = (RatingBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.notas);
    }

    public Aluno pegarAluno()
    {
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
        aluno.setNome(String.valueOf(campoNome.getText()));
        aluno.setEndereco(String.valueOf(campoEndereco.getText()));
        aluno.setSite(String.valueOf(campoSitesPessoais.getText()));
        aluno.setTelefone(String.valueOf(campoTelefone.getText()));
        aluno.setNota(Double.valueOf(campoNotas.getRating()));

        return aluno;
    }
}
```

Comment: A variável `campoNotas` é uma view RatingBar ?

Comment: Acho melhor você colocar o código completo. Da activity ou do Fragment que faz uso dessa view

Comment: A variável campoNotas é uma view RatingBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha resposta é baseada nos códigos que você postou. Talvez, a solução que vou apresentar não seja a mais adequada.

**Análise**

Você tem um atributo do `FormularioHelper` do tipo `EditText` chamado `campoNotas`:

```
private EditText campoNotas;
```

No seu construtor, provavelmente, você tenta setar esse atributo para ser usado depois:

```
RatingBar campoNotas = (RatingBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.notas);
```

Porém, acima, o que você criou foi uma nova variável. Então, depois você tenta usar `pegarAluno` como se fosse um `RatingBar`. Mas ele não é. Ele continua sendo um `EditText`. Logo o erro é acusado pois a função `getRating` no `EditText` não existe.

```
 aluno.setNota(Double.valueOf(campoNotas.getRating()));
```

**Solução**

Você pode criar um outro atributo com outro nome e construir-lo:

```
private RatingBar campoNotasRating;

public FormularioHelper(FormularioActivity activity)
{
    // aqui estou setando um valor para o atributo
    this.campoNotasRating = (RatingBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.notas);
}
```

E depois usá-lo:

```
 aluno.setNota(Double.valueOf(this.campoNotasRating.getRating()));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Código funcionando**

```
package com.alura.magnero2018.agendaalura;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;

import com.alura.magnero2018.agendaalura.FormularioActivity;
import com.alura.magnero2018.agendaalura.R;


import alura.modelo.Aluno;

public class FormularioHelper 
{
    private EditText campoNome;
    private EditText campoEndereco;
    private EditText campoSitesPessoais;
    private EditText campoTelefone;
    private RatingBar campoNotas;

    public EditText getCampoNome() {
        return campoNome;
    }

    public void setCampoNome(EditText campoNome) {
        this.campoNome = campoNome;
    }

    public EditText getCampoEndereco() {
        return campoEndereco;
    }

    public void setCampoEndereco(EditText campoEndereco) {
        this.campoEndereco = campoEndereco;
    }

    public EditText getCampoSitesPessoais() {
        return campoSitesPessoais;
    }

    public void setCampoSitesPessoais(EditText campoSitesPessoais) {
        this.campoSitesPessoais = campoSitesPessoais;
    }

    public EditText getCampoTelefone() {
        return campoTelefone;
    }

    public void setCampoTelefone(EditText campoTelefone) {
        this.campoTelefone = campoTelefone;
    }

    public RatingBar getCampoNotas() {
        return campoNotas;
    }

    public void setCampoNotas(RatingBar campoNotas) {
        this.campoNotas = campoNotas;
    }


    public FormularioHelper(FormularioActivity activity)
    {
        EditText campoNome = activity.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        EditText campoEndereco = activity.findViewById(R.id.endereco);
        EditText campoSitesPessoais = activity.findViewById(R.id.sitesPessoais);
        EditText campoTelefone = activity.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
        RatingBar campoNotas = (RatingBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.notas);
    }

    public Aluno pegarAluno()
    {
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
        aluno.setNome(String.valueOf(campoNome.getText()));
        aluno.setEndereco(String.valueOf(campoEndereco.getText()));
        aluno.setSite(String.valueOf(campoSitesPessoais.getText()));
        aluno.setTelefone(String.valueOf(campoTelefone.getText()));
        aluno.setNota(Double.valueOf(campoNotas.getProgress()));

        return aluno;
    }
}
```